# Don't have a bench for bodyweight back extensions, alternatives?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, home-exercise, lower-back

I don't have bench where I can do bodyweight back extensions, nor the space to put one. What are alternatives to work out the lower back?

I'm only aware of one - lying flat on the back, place on foot on bench or and raise lower back, works, hamstrings, glute and somewhat lower back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really is no need to use a bench for any of this. The "hanging" part of the back raise can be handled by dead lifts, good mornings, those type of exercise where you raise to an upright position against resistance.

The only part of the exercise you describe that isn't worked can be worked satisfactorily simply by laying on your stomach, and raising your chest off of the ground, keeping your legs and hips flat on the floor.

Another possibility, although space may be an issue, is to use a Swiss ball for the same motion. Work on balance and stability first, as the ball is more mobile than a bench.

Answer (score 1):

You can give [this](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/hyperextensions-with-no-hyperextension-bench) workout a shot if you have someone that can spot you.

[image]
[image]

You could also consider doing some [stiff leg dead-lifts](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/hyperextensions-with-no-hyperextension-bench) and [standard dead-lifts](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/barbell-deadlift), but these don't meet your "bodyweight" requirement.

Comment: If I had a bench like this I would try to use a rope and a towel  to fix my legs. I don't, but it's still a good idea.